# requireJS optimzer (r.js) generate code with exception

Tags: requirejs, r.js, requirejs-optimizer

I am trying to 'optimze' my requireJS/Backbone project
I succeeded running r.js under node environment, the problem is the output from the r.js compiler
throws 'unexpected identifier'

index.html has the following

```
<script data-main="assets/core/system/init"  src="assets/core/system/require.js"></script>
```

r.js config as the following

```
({
 paths: {
    models: '../models',
    views: '../views',
    templates: '../templates',
    app: '../app',
    utils: '../utils',
    collections: '../collections',
    dataTypes: '../utils/dataTypes',
    elementTypes: '../utils/elementTypes',
    controls: '../controls',
    modals: '../modals',
    common: '../common'//,

},
 shim: {
    'backbone': {
        deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
        exports: 'Backbone'
    },

    'underscore': {
        exports: '_'
    },
    'jqueryUI': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    'jquery': {
        exports: '$'
    },
    'bootstrap': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    'common/highcharts/main': {
        exports: 'highcharts',
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    'app/config': {
        deps: ['underscore', 'jquery']
    },
      'common/placeHolder/main':{
        deps: ['jquery'],
        exports: 'placeHolder',
        init: function(jquery){
          jquery('input, textarea').placeholder();
        }
    },
    'validation': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
},
baseUrl : "assets/core/system",
name: "init",
out: "main.js",
removeCombined: true,
findNestedDependencies: true
```

})

Comment: *'unexpected identifier'* - where? Is there a stack trace?

Comment: the exception as the following - 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier main.js:1', The 'main.js' start like this: 'define("app/config",[],function(){var'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the following syntax

```
$('<div>',{
  style: 'position:absolute;'
});
```

The above syntax is creating element width attributes using jquery.
The **compiler** and seems like **IE7** too doesn't like it.

To correct it, I change it to the following. ( adding comma -'- to the  property name )

```
$('<div>',{
  'style': 'position:absolute;'
});
```